# Fast and Elegant way to control string is empty or not in C#

Tags: c#

I am try to control multiple strings variables is empty or not at once:

My first approach is very simple:

```
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(val1) && string.isNullOrEmpty(val2) && string.isNullOrEmpty(val3))
```

My second way looks like this

```
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(val1 + val2 + val3))
```

Which one is fastest and elegant?
Is there any options to do this operation?

Comment: The first is definitely more readable.

Comment: Does it have to be the fastest thing possible, or just fast enough? In 99% of the cases `val1 + val2 + val3` is fast enough.

Comment: About *fastest*: Try it out! About *elegant*: That's quite subjective and depends on if you like short code more than logical code. The first example is the logical one.

Comment: The first one is the safest.  With the second one if you have a case where the empty string causes one of the val variables to NOT get initialized then I suspect you will get an object not set or null value error.

Comment: Without meaning to confuse the issue, it is important to point out that the two code snippets aren't equivalent.

Comment: @Brian - even if all three strings are `null`, the second one will not fail. The concatenation then results in String.Empty

Comment: The two instructions have different meanings: the first will return true if *one of the string* is null or empty, while the second will return true if *all the strings* are null or empty... So it's not about performance or elegance, it's about correctness ;)

Comment: The two code fragments are not equivalent: the first one returns `true` if at least one string is null or empty, while the second returns `true` if *all* strings are either equal null or empty.

Comment: Sorry I edited the first operation :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first was faster in my test (just had to): 6ms vs. 70ms and that was on 10,000,000 iterations each (so the speed difference probably doesn't matter very much unless you're doing this on a massive scale).
Anyway, i find the first to be more clear.

Also it doesn't rely on behavior of `IsNullOrEmpty` that is not immediately obvious (you might just as well think that passing `null` parameters causes an `ArgumentNullException` if you don't know better), which i think is important.

Note: The test was with all variables set to null, but setting them to other values confirms it, the longer the strings get, the longer option 2 takes, while option 1 stays at about 30ms max.

Also, the first returns true if any of the strings is null or empty, while the second does it only if **all** of them are null or empty. So it's not the same check.

Comment: Can you update your performance test data with || changed to &&, as in the edited question? Thx

Comment: On average it's no difference, && and || are basically both single instructions.

Comment: Although atomic ANDs and ORs take the same time, there's a difference because an OR chain `(a || b || c || ...)` will stop on the first TRUE, while an AND chain will stop on the first FALSE.

Comment: That's why i said, on average. Assuming an even distribution of true and false. Of course you can speed it up if you put the variables most likely to prevent the following checks at the beginning. That saves you a few milliseconds each 10,000,000 iterations.

Answer (score 3):

They are not equivalent. The first one checks if any of them is null. The second one checks if all of them are null. Make up your mind.

Answer (score 1):

`if(string.isNullOrEmpty(val1 + val2 + val3))` seems to me the fastest

I would advice you to also use `concat`

but behind the scenes it uses the `'+'` operator.

I think this is the fastest.

If it werent nullable I suggest summing their length and check `==0`
[image]

[image]

Comment: `wstrcpy()` indeed takes managed pointers (not references, to be precise) as its arguments. But it still does its job by copying regions of memory, so the longer the strings get, the longer `Concat()` executes. FYI, if strings have 1000 characters in them, then the Concat approach is 180(!) times slower.

Comment: I know. it is recommanded bellow 4 to use concat . after that stringbuilder

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
new string[] {val1, val2, val2}.All(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s))
```

Or something similar.

Comment: This is definitely slower than the other ways.

Answer (score 1):

I would expect 'fastest' to depend on how often you expect one or more of the strings to actually be null or empty.

For example, if val1 is often going to be null or empty then the first option is likely to be best; if they are all rarely going to be null or empty then I'm not sure of the answer, but it can't take more than five minutes to knock together a few benchmarks for your particular expectations.

(Also, note that the two options don't do the same thing, the first is true if ANY of them are null or empty the second is not doing that)

Answer (score 0):

The second one:

```
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(val1 + val2 + val3))
```

equals

```
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(val1) && string.isNullOrEmpty(val2) && string.isNullOrEmpty(val3))
```

(note the `&&` instead of `||`)
but will create an intermediate string, whereas my second version will not create extra strings and stop checking as soon as one string is not empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number of string variables, then I think it is more readable to use the first construction:

```
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(val1) &&
   string.isNullOrEmpty(val2) &&
   string.isNullOrEmpty(val3))
{
}
```

This way, it seems like each variable is treated separately, and this code is a little easier to change if you need to treat one of the variables in another way.

But in case all of the string variables are to be treated in the same way, they are very likely to be represented as an array or another kind of enumeration. Then it's definitely better to use John M Gant's suggestion:

```
if(myStrings.All(s => string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)))
{
}
```